# How to show that this is the absolute value of a complex number?

Tags: complex-numbers, absolute-value

Let: $$z=a+b i$$

> Prove that: $$|z|=\Re(z \exp (-i \Im(\log (z))))$$

As a starting point Mathematica tells me that:
$$\Re(z \exp (-i \Im(\log (z))))=a \cos (\Im(\log (a+b i)))+b \sin (\Im(\log (a+b i)))$$

And I know that:
$$|z|=\sqrt {a^2+b^2}$$ by the definition in Wikipedia and from my mathematical handbook.

How do I proceed from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula only makes sense if $\lvert z \rvert > 0$, since otherwise the log isn't defined. Let $a=r\cos{\theta}$, $b=r\sin{\theta}$, $r > 0$, $0 \leq \theta < 2\pi $. Then by Euler's formula, $z=re^{i\theta}$ and
$$ \log{z} = \log{r} + i(\theta+2n\pi) $$
for some integer $n$. So the imaginary part is $\theta+2n\pi$. Then
$$ \exp{(-i\Im(\log{z}))} = e^{-i\theta - 2n\pi i} = e^{-i\theta} $$
But then
$$ z\exp{(-i\Im(\log{z}))} = z e^{-i\theta} = re^{i\theta-i\theta} = r = \lvert z \rvert, $$
and so in fact the last $\Re$ is unnecessary.

To do it only using $a$ and $b$ is a pain, firstly because finding the imaginary part of the logarithm's unpleasant, and then finding $e^{-i \Im(\log{z}) }$ is even worse. Much better to work in polar form.